# How do i scrape something from multiple divs under one parent div in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hello i am new to scraping, I want to scrape some text from multiple divs that are under one parent div.. I have attached the screen shot of the html. [image: html screenshot]
Under the class "partnerships_cont"
there are multiple divs with class "items".. from these divs i want to scrape the div i marked. But i run into an error.
This is the code i used:

```
def get_partnerships(driver):
    WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class, 'partnerships-cont')]/div[1]")))
    partnerships_cont = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'partnerships-cont')]")
    items = partnerships_cont.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'item')]")

    for item in items:
        div = item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]")
        text = div.find_element_by_xpath("//div").text
        print(text)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_py\chromedriver_win32.exe')
driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/ZRX/full-disclosure')
get_partnerships(driver)
```

No matter what i do i get this error:

```
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

please could you tell me why i get this error? and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception because it should be `find_elements()` instead of `find_element()`. Change below code and try

```
items = partnerships_cont.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'item')]")
```

Optimized way of your code to grab name and description:

```
def get_partnerships(driver):
    items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.partnerships-cont>.item')

    for item in items:
        name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('div.name.fv1')
        desc = item.find_element_by_css_selector('div.description.fv1')
        print(name.text)
        print(desc.text)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_py\chromedriver_win32.exe')
driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/ZRX/full-disclosure')
get_partnerships(driver)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple `css selector` achieve that.Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_py\chromedriver_win32.exe')
driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/ZRX/full-disclosure')
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".partnerships-cont>.item>.info-cont>.name.fv1")))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

**Output**:

```
Harbor
Aragon
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything to me